# I wanted to check login users follow the search user or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

i want to check login users, follow the search user or not, if follow, true if not,false show in output i need help php cod
MY CODE IS

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` where user_id='$userid' AND session_id='$session_id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($result->num_rows>0)
    {
        //user_array
    $user_query="SELECT * FROM users";
$user_query_result=mysqli_query($conn,$user_query);
if($user_query_result->num_rows>0)
 { 
    $user_array=array(); 
while ($row_users = $user_query_result->fetch_assoc()) 
{   
    $user_id=$row_users['user_id'];
    $user_name=$row_users['fast_name']." ".$row_users['last_name'];
    $user_pic_path=$row_users['user_pic_path'];

    $follower=array();
    $followers=array();
    $followed_query="SELECT * FROM followers where follower_id=".$user_id;
    $followed_result=mysqli_query($conn,$followed_query);
    while($followed_row=$followed_result->fetch_assoc())
    {   
        $follower=$followed_row['user_id'];
    if($follower==$user_id)
    {
        $followers=TRUE;
    }
                //array_push($followers,$followed_row['user_id']);
    }
    $images=array();
    $images_query="SELECT * FROM image where user_id=".$user_id;
    $image_result=mysqli_query($conn,$images_query);
    while($image_row=$image_result->fetch_assoc())
    {   
        $images[]=$image_row['image_path'];
    }

    $user[] = array(
    /*"user_id"=>$user_id,*/
    "user_name"=>$user_name,
    "user_pic_path"=>$user_pic_path,
    "follower"=>$followers,
    "images"=>$images
    );
    //add in user_array
    array_push($user_array,$user);
}
$response['session']=TRUE;
$response['status']=TRUE;
$response['msg']="user data find successfully";
$response['user_detail']=$user;
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

MY OUTPUT IS

```
// 20180104175035
// http://localhost/1111.php?userid=2&session_id=953455543

{
  "session": true,
  "status": true,
  "msg": "user data find successfully",
  "user_detail": [
    {
      "user_name": "asad ali",
      "user_pic_path": "localhost/uploads/image/9152108abc",
      "follower": [

      ],
      "images": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/7947861Discover All In One.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "asim kabeer",
      "user_pic_path": "localhost/uploads/image/1952108xyz",
      "follower": [

      ],
      "images": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/1787860Discover All In One.png",
        "localhost/uploads/image/2152108Mart Zone - All in one.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "saad hussain",
      "user_pic_path": "localhost/uploads/image/5152108ytp",
      "follower": [

      ],
      "images": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/1474008Mart Zone - All in one.png",
        "localhost/uploads/image/6547860Discover All In One.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "nazeer hussain",
      "user_pic_path": "localhost/uploads/image/7352108trp",
      "follower": [

      ],
      "images": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/1547860Discover All In One.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "asad zahoor",
      "user_pic_path": "localhost/images/ftftft",
      "follower": [

      ],
      "images": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/1081552Mart Zone - All in one.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "ali hussain",
      "user_pic_path": "localhost/images/sduhsud.png",
      "follower": [

      ],
      "images": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/5547860Discover All In One.png"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

why follower does not show the value i want true or false if follow then show true my follower table schema are following
user_id=>1,2,3,4,5,6
follower_user_id=>2,3,5,3,4,1

Comment: What is the structure of the `followers` table? Add one example row of it to your question.

Comment: user_id=>1,2,3,4,5,6                                                                                     follower_id=>4,5,6,3,2,3                it means user 4 follow user 1,user 5 follow the user 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row_followed = $result_followed->fetch_assoc())
     {
       //array_push($followers,$row_followed['user_id']);
       $age=array($userid=>$row_followed['follower_id']);

        foreach($age as $x => $value)
        {
         if($x==$value)
         {
            $followers=TRUE;
         }
         elseif($x!==$value)
         {
            $followers=FALSE;
         }
        }


     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure, that below condition is failing

```
if($follower==$user_id)
{
```

I'm not sure about the data, so I can't comment much. But, I would suggest to debug your SQL one more time and check, if you are getting expected output from SQL

```
$followed_query="SELECT * FROM followers where follower_id=".$user_id;
$followed_result=mysqli_query($conn,$followed_query);
while($followed_row=$followed_result->fetch_assoc())
{   
    $follower=$followed_row['user_id'];
if($follower==$user_id)
```

**Side note : -** why can't you simply use  `follower_id=user_id` in SQL ?

---

```
$followers=array();
if(1==1)
{
     $followers=TRUE;
}

$user[] = array("follower"=>$followers,);
print_r ($user);
```

Output :

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [follower] => 1
        )
```

Whereas, below case return empty array, which is actually your case

```
if(1==2)
{
     $followers=TRUE;
}

$user[] = array("follower"=>$followers,);
print_r ($user);
```

Output :

```
 [0] => Array
        (
        )
```

Comment: His initial problem is, that the field `follower_id` in his DB contains a comma separated varchar of user ids. Checking if that list is equal with the `user_id` is therefore indeed incorrect, as you stated in the beginnig. ( as long as the user is not the only follower )

Comment: @AllWorld I'm not sure, what are you saying